# Add offset to smooth scroll with a navbar using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I tried to look up multiple solutions like I tried `target:before` for example but none of them really worked. My idea is to have a smooth scroll with an offset of -100px so that my fixed header is not blocking the content of the section. I found this solution which is using `a href` as a reference.

now is it possible to change that reference to `button` with the id "content"?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-100
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
});
```

rest of my code:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 300vh;
}

#wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background-color: darkgray;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
  <html>
  <nav id="navwrapper">
    <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/navbar fixed.js"></script>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top selectSection">
      <h1 id="titel">HEADLINE</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" type="button" data-number="1" class="active navb">content1</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
 
  
  <div id="wrap" class="contentSection wrapper">
  <section id="content1" class="content" data-number="1">
    <div>
    content 1
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. After googling even more I found [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/GRJvozN)  using
`scroll-margin-top:;` which worked in my case!